# PutSQL Nifi processor not sending any data

Tags: mysql, processor, apache-nifi

I have had the processor running for 24 hours.  At different points (I have 3 different PutSQL processor on the same Connection Pool Service), the data has stopped being sent to sql.  Now I can see data coming in to the processor but nothing ever comes out[image: PutSQL not outputing anything]

Comment: Is there anything in the logs (logs/nifi-app.log for example) that indicates an error or warning from the PutSQL processor? How often was data being written to it?  From your picture I can see the processor is stopped, when you start it does it work again?

Comment: Through trial and error I found that switching Support Fragmented Transactions from False to True fixed the issue.  I am not sure I understand what Support Fragmented Transactions does though.

Comment: It can be a bit complicated and was originally created to complement ConvertJSONtoSQL, basically it will wait for all flow files with the same attribute value (for ID and count), then send all the SQL statements at once, rather than one at a time, the latter can be inefficient.

Comment: Ok, great, thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: Would you like to convert your solution (and my light explanation if you wish) to an answer so this question isn't "unanswered"? Otherwise I can do it so you can accept it (but didn't want to steal your points :)

Comment: the mentioned solution didn't work for me though, m getting the same result as in the image shared by @Jean-Philippe, and my  Support Fragmented Transactions also has the value True, still no data is insert into my database.

Comment: @Ranjan do you have an error message?  Try running the query you are sending directly in SQL and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

Through trial and error I found that switching Support Fragmented Transactions from False to True fixed the issue.